# want to show Unsuccess Message for not running mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug

I Want to show 'unsuceess message' in node js when mongodb is not running. My code shows success or unsuccess only when mongod is running.but when i shutdown mongo .my webpage keeps on loading on submitting form. and nothing happens/shows.

Below is the code :

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
var favicon = require('serve-favicon')
.
.
.
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/ContactForm', {useNewUrlParser: true});
port = 5500;
var ContactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    phone: Number,  
    email: String,
    Company_name: String,
    desc: String,
  });
var Contact = mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema);
.
.
.
.
.
app.post("/Contact_Us",(req,res)=>{
    var Myform = new Contact(req.body);
    Myform.save()
    .then(item => {
        res.status(200).render('contact.pug',{ messageq: true});
        res.end();
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        res.status(400).send("Unable to save the message , Please Try after some time");
    });
});

.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/ContactForm', { useNewUrlParser: true }).
catch(error => console.log(error.message));
```

Or for the custom error message:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/ContactForm', { useNewUrlParser: true }).
catch(error => console.log("unable to connect to server));
```

Thanks

Comment: thanks For the reply sir, But i want to show user message like :- " Sorry something went wrong message on that contact.pug page .... In details:- when mongo is running .and when user submit their form, page render on that page with a message success which is handled using 'messageq ===true' when it succesfully runs. i'm handling it in contact.pug with If statement. But when i mongo is not running then i want to show message to user that 'Something went wrong or somthing on that page ' when they submit their form.